# Getting wrong readings when trying to plot CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, spyder

My csv file looks like the following:

[image]

As you see there are 7 columns with comma separated. I have spent hours to read and plot the first column starting with 31364 with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=None, names=['colA','colB','colC','colD','colE','colF','colG'])
y = df['colA']
plt.plot(y)
```

But the code outputs this plot which does not match the data at all:

[image]

I'm using Spyder with Anaconda. What could be the problem?

Comment: Just to be correct: this csv has 8 columns, not 7 (7 with data and one empty).

Answer (score 0):

Is column A all values in the 31,000 range? You're not plotting the whole file.

edit: Don't know what result you're looking for. In your code, the first column in your csv is used as the index to the dataframe (after you read the csv, enter 'df', no quotes, at the python prompt to see what your dataset looks like.
If you don't want the first column in the csv as an index, add 'index_col=False', no quotes, to the parameters when you read the csv in.
Also, not a good idea to end lines in a csv wit the delimiter, comma in this case.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. The screenshot shows the beginning of the data. Do you want to see the whole data?

Comment: No. Run df.head() to see the first 5 lines of the dataframe, df tail() to see the last 5. Everything in colA (which is what you're plotting in y) is in the 31000 range. Looking at your data, every value in colA is between 31343 and 31367. The scale of your plot will only show these values as a vertical line.

Comment: Can you help me with that Im not a programmer just need to plot the data.

Comment: I can't download the file. Restricted work computer.